# Select query inside ENCRYPTBYKEY function in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I am trying to decrypt a table column and store it in a different table by opening a symmetric key and I find the below query to be erroneous:

```
create table dbo.Secrets (
Secret varbinary(400)
)
go

create view dbo.openSecrets
as
    select cast(decryptbykey(Secret) as varchar(200)) as OpenSecret
    from dbo.Secrets
go

open symmetric key [SymKey] 
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [SymCert]
go


insert into dbo.Secrets (Secret)
values (ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SymKey'), (select col_test from dbo.tbltest)));

select *
from dbo.openSecrets;

close symmetric key [SymKey];

select *
from dbo.openSecrets;
```

The error that I see is: SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

The problem is with this line:

```
 values (ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SymKey'), (select col_test from dbo.tbltest)));
```

Expected output:

[image]

This should be the output for select statements In and out of decryption.

But I don't know to fix the internal select statement. Any help?!

Comment: I *assume* `dbo.tbltest` has more than 1 row in is. What **scalar** value are you expecting `(select col_test from dbo.tbltest)` to return here?

Comment: yes problem is with that select statement. col_test is encrypted. So I want to decrypt that. I will post the screenshot of expected output in the question now

Comment: `INSERT .. SELECT ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SymKey'), col_test) FROM dbo.tbltest`.